# How do i add an image in a div?

Tags: javascript

I need to insert a image to be zoom in and out but some website told me that it is suppose to be use with path="image url". The image didn't appear so i want to use background-image: url("image url"). So how do i put it in to allow image to show?

```
<style type="text/css">

#html{
    height:100%;
}

#body{
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;

}

#hr{ 
    border:0;
    width:50%;
}


</style>


<body>


<div id="outerDiv0">
  <div id="outerDiv" style="position:relative;height:99%;width:100%;border:1px solid black;overflow:hidden;">
```

```
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 10px; z-index: 1">
      <img src="zoomin_off.gif"
           onclick="ZoomIn()" alt="zoomin"/>
    </div>
<div style="position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 90px; z-index: 1">
      <img src="zoomout_off.gif"
           onclick="ZoomOut()" alt="zoomout"/>
    </div>

    <div id="Nav" style="display:none;position: absolute; top: 70px; left: 20px; z-index: 1"><div><a href="javascript:slidePrev();" id="slidePrev"><img src="prev.gif" alt="prev"/></a></div>
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 79px;"><a href="javascript:slideNext();" id="slideNext"><img src="next.gif" alt="next"/></a></div></div>

    <div id="imageTiles" style="position:relative;top:0;left:0;z-index:0;width:100%;"></div>
    <div id="imageLabels" style="position:relative;top:0;left:0;z-index:1;width:900000px;height:900000px;"></div>
    </div>

  <div id="overlay"><div id="theScale"></div><div id="theInfo">
  </div>
  <div id="Thumb0"><div id="Thumb"></div><div id="Thumb2"></div></div>
  </div>

  <div id="wheelMode">Mouse Wheel:<input type="radio" onclick="wheelMode1()"          />&nbsp;Zoom<input type="radio" onclick="wheelMode2()" />&nbsp;Next/Prev</div>
  <div id="coords" style="position:absolute;top:2px;right:10px;z-index:10;"></div>



  </div>
```

Comment: can you make fiddle? and show code

Comment: Please provide us with more info

Comment: What code is there with you?

Answer (score 1):

Without any example code we can only guess. Maybe your div did not have any dimensions. Try adding width and height with css to your div:

```
<div style="width:300px;height:300px;background:url('http://webpage/path/to/image.jpg')"></div>
```

Comment: I tried the code already still doesn't work. it makes the zoom in button lower though.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

CSS:

```
.Bg{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background-image:url('imagepath');
 }
```

HTML:

```
 <div class='Bg'></div>
```

Comment: it didn't work but the controls are still there. but no image still

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to understand what exactly you want to do,however if you want to add background image to div you can do it as follows

```
<div class="show">
some text
</div>
```

in CSS

```
.show
{
background-image:url('paper.gif');
//other css properties of div
}
```

[ref](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp)

Comment: It didn't work but the word i type is above the zoom in button